# Reading an xml file in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, data-storage

I have saved the IP configuration of the server in a xml file in /Simulate/Configuration.xml in my android internal storage

Configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<IPconfig>

<ipAddress>172.**.***.***</ipAddress>
<port>5000</port>

</IPconfig>
```

The code to access the ipaddress and port number

```
try {
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();
File FXmlFile = new File (sdcard, "/ Simulate / Configuration.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement (). normalize ();
NodeList nlist = doc.getElementsByTagName ("IPconfig");
for (int temp = 0; temp <nList.getLength (); temp + +) {
Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
if (nNode.getNodeType () == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
SERVERIP= eElement.getAttribute("ipAddress");
System.out.println ("server ip:" + SERVERIP);
SERVERPORT= eElement.getAttribute("port");
System.out.println ("Server port:" + ServerPort);
}
}
}catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I print SERVERIP and SERVERPORT both return a null. How can I get the ipaddress and port value from the xml? Any help is appreciated. Also if there is a better way to specify the ipconfig of server.

Comment: You don't have `ipAddress` or `port` attributes in your XML. You have values.

Comment: You can post it as an answer

Comment: no problem :)
it is trivial, comment is absolutely enough here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered because of Andrey Voitenkov hint that I had used elements and not attributes :)

```
********EDIT*******
SERVERIP= eElement.getElementsByTagName("ipAddress").item(0).getTextContent();
System.out.println("server    ip:"+SERVERIP);
SERVERPORT= eElement.getElementsByTagName("port").item(0).getTextContent();
System.out.println("server port:"+SERVERPORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;


    public class Handler extends DefaultHandler
    {
public String ipAddress;
public String port;
public StringBuffer  sbBuffer;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sbBuffer = new StringBuffer();
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ipAddress"))
        ipAddress = sbBuffer.toString();
    else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("port"))
        port = sbBuffer.toString();
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
{
    sbBuffer.append(ch,start,length);
}


    }
```